# How to find minimum value from a list using while loop at the same time not using min function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am kinda of new to python and I recently came across this problem which I cannot figure which is how to find the minimum value of a list without using the min or max function in python. The below is my code:

```
#Prompt user to enter a minimum of 5 round trip times separated with commas
roundTrips = input('Please enter at least 5 round trips seprated by ",": ')



#Check closest object
def closest_object(roundTrips):
    roundTrips = list(roundTrips.split(','))
    count = 0
    minimum = 0
    if len(roundTrips)<=4:
        print('error')
    else:
        while count<len(roundTrips):
            positions = roundTrips[count]
            count += 1
            if minimum or (int(positions)<minimum):
                minimum = positions
                print(minimum)

    #Perform the parsing of roundTrips input here

    closestObject = []

    print('The closest object is',closestObject) #Modify to display the closest object

    return closestObject#Do not remove this line
```

Comment: Why can't you use `min/max`? Is this homework?

Comment: Yep, my lecturer told me that it was possible to find to minimum value without using min function. Well, I attempted to do what he said but to no avail hence I am seeking help at this fourm

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [10, 1,2,3,4,5]
ans = lst[0]
i=0
while(i<len(lst)):
    if lst[i] < ans:
        ans = lst[i]
    i+=1
print(ans)
```

This would work but I don't think for such simple task you need to ask question on stackoverflow. you can find many similar answers on internet

Comment: It works thanks, man! But where your thought process when you constructed this code?

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_min(l):
  min = l[0]
  for i in l[1:]:
    if i<min: min = i
  return(min)

la=[4,2,3,4,5,3,2,4,44,-2]

print(find_min(la))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in why your code fails instead of copy-paste an answer :

I don't know what `if minimum` is supposed to accomplish but what it does is executes the loop each time that `minimum != 0` because then it evaluates to `True` and since the `or` is short-circuit, `int(positions) < minimum` is not checked then, so just delete the `if minimum`.

And you should initialize the minimum to the first element of your list because you can't be sure that 0 is in it.